# How to increase Airtable api rate limit?

Tags: rest, airtable, rate-limiting

We are using airtable rest APIs to manage our employee's data.
In the airtable support article, it was written that the airtable API has a rate limit of 5 requests per second per base.

Here is the article link: [https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/203313985-Public-REST-API#:~:text=Yes%2C%20the%20public%20API%20has,section%20of%20the%20API%20documentation](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/203313985-Public-REST-API#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20the%20public%20API%20has,section%20of%20the%20API%20documentation).

So if we upgrade to a pro or enterprise plan then can we get a more request limit on api? Or is there any other way to increase airtable API request limit?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I came across your post when I was doing my own research. Unfortunately, airtable has a fixed 5 requests per second limit for all pricing levels. There's no way to increase this limit. However, to bypass this, I've implemented a simple node/express server that acts as a middleman to cache the airtables data and serve it to the client. I used this article as a guideline : https://itnext.io/how-we-serve-millions-of-pageviews-using-a-nodejs-airtable-proxy-fdb4ec693720